# How run a script with variable in the name under PowerShell in GitHub workflow / actions

Tags: powershell, batch-file, github, github-actions

I'm implementing a GitHub workflow and I need to run a batch (*.bat) script under PowerShell with a variable part. This doesn't seem to work. A simple batch script is running fine. But when I try to insert a variable into its name it doesn't

I've tried these  with no success:

```
run: |
  $i=2
  call "myscript_$i.bat"
```

---

```
run: |
  $i=2
  .\myscript_$i.bat
```

---

```
run: |
  $i=2
  .\myscript_${env:i}.bat
```

---

Is there any Obi-Wan who can help on this? )

Comment: What happens if you use `& '.\script.bat'`?

Comment: @NekoMusume, please see the updated description.

Comment: Try removing `env` and just using `${i}` and see if that works? Maybe try `$($i)`, it might work

Comment: @NekoMusume, thanks. Please see below. I've found a solution to how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some experimenting this solution works:

```
run |
  $i=2
  Invoke-Expression ".\myscript_$i.bat"
```

Answer (score 2):

While [your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122878/45375) works, [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

To invoke a command by a name / path based on a *quoted string* and/or containing a *variable reference* or *expression*, use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-):

```
run |
  $i=2
  & ".\myscript_$i.bat"
```

(In this particular case, you could even omit the enclosing `"`.)